# Xcode 14: custom inputAccessoryView appears prematurely, causing broken push animation

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, xcode14, inputaccessoryview

After upgrading to **xcode 14**, override of the inputAccessoryView of a UIViewController causes animation issues during push / pop UINavigationController transitions. (on xcode 13, no issues)

```
    override var inputAccessoryView: UIView? {
        return myCustomInputBar
    }

    override var canBecomeFirstResponder: Bool{
        return true
    }
```

The two main issues are:

1. The inputAccessoryView flashes / appears above the current view you're transitioning away from. (inputAccessoryView should display only within the confines of it's UIViewController)
2. The push / pop transition animation is not smooth. The new screen moves forward and then backwards briefly before continuing forward again.

https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/721301 (this issue mentions the same thing)

Here's screenshots of the inputAccessoryView appearing prematurely:

[image] [image]

Here's Videos of the issue:
[Broken push animation / input bar flash](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1lDgb9IOQn5-0YEA3VigWyx4MmfJG5dLs/view?usp=sharing)

[Broken pop animation / input bar flash](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1aEdAaxDjSyOczxEh1abWukw2HRWYBxLI/view?usp=sharing)

Current workaround:
Only show inputBarAccessoryView in viewDidAppear, which fixes the animation problems during the navigationController transition but this causes a significant delay.

Has anyone else run into this issue? Any help would be very much appreciated.