Laggy InputAccessoryView appearance animation
Here's an animation how it looks like:

Notice how it flashes first before animating into its final position. It's also happening on real device.
Initially thought this was an issue with my custom view for InputAccessoryView, but after testing with plain UIView with only the background color set to red, it appears to be a bug within UIKit.
Here's a minimal reproducible example:
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    lazy var pushViewControllerButton: UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton()
        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        button.backgroundColor = .systemBlue
        button.setTitle("Push View Controller", for: .normal)
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(showViewController), for: .touchUpInside)
        return button
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = .white
        setupConstraints()
    }

    private func setupConstraints() {
        view.addSubview(pushViewControllerButton)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            pushViewControllerButton.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.centerXAnchor),
            pushViewControllerButton.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.centerYAnchor),
            pushViewControllerButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 35)
        ])
    }

    @objc private func showViewController() {
        let viewController = ViewControllerWithAccessoryView()
        navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true)
    }


}

class ViewControllerWithAccessoryView: UIViewController {

    let accessoryView: UIView = {
        let view = UIView()
        view.backgroundColor = .systemRed
        view.frame.size.height = 80
        return view
    }()

    override var inputAccessoryView: UIView? {
        return accessoryView
    }

    override var canBecomeFirstResponder: Bool {
        return true
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = .white
    }
}


Because the inputAccessoryView is not in the view hierarchy of ViewControllerWithAccessoryView, I'm not sure you will be able to avoid that flash and have the inputAccessoryView slide-in with the controller. You could delay it, and have it animate up from the bottom in viewDidAppear

Just found another post with the same issue -- and no resolution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76447766/xcode-14-custom-inputaccessoryview-appears-prematurely-causing-broken-push-ani

@DonMag I've settled on not using the inputAccessoryView entirely. I've added my custom UIView for input accessory directly to the ViewControllerWithAccessoryView and constrained it to keyboardLayoutGuide. This achieves what I initially wanted by overriding inputAccessoryView without visual bugs.
I know that inputAccessoryView responsible for many things, so completely avoiding it may not be suitable in some cases, but it works for my app.

I've decided to avoid overriding inputAccessoryView property. Instead I've added my accessoryView directly to the ViewController and constrained it to the keyboardLayoutGuide. Now I've been told that avoiding inputAccessoryView may not be an option because it's responsible for other things and provides better layout in cases like detached keyboard in iPadOS, external keyboard, etc. But it works for my app and behaves better, helped me resolve other visual bugs with accessoryView animations.
